# How to match and extract using regex - Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm taking a look how to use regex and trying to figure out how to extract the Latitude and Longitude, no matter if the number is positive or negative, right after the "?ll=" as shown below:

https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=**-6.148222,106.8462**&q=loc:-6.148222,106.8462&

I have used the following code in python to get only the first digits marked above:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'popup-gmaps'}):
    lnk = str(link.get('href'))
    print(lnk)
    m = re.match('-?\d+(?!.*ll=)(?!&q=loc)*', lnk)
    print(m)
    #lat, *long = m.split(',')
    #print(lat)
    #print(long)
```

The result I got isn't what I was expecting:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-6.148222,106.8462&q=loc:-6.148222,106.8462&
None
```

I'm getting "None" rather than the value "-6.148222,106.8462". I also tried to split those numbers into two variables called lat and long, but since I always got "None" python stops processing with "exit code 1" until I comment lines.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()` cause `re.match()` is used for exact matches.

This can solve the problem

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'popup-gmaps'}):
    lnk = str(link.get('href'))
    m = re.search(r"(-?\d*\.\d*),(-?\d*\.\d*)", lnk)
    print(m.group())
    print("lat = "+m.group(1))
    print("lng = "+m.group(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a proper URL parser, using regex here is asking for problems in case the URL embedded in the page you are crawling is changing in a way that will break the regex you use.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-6.148222,106.8462&q=loc:-6.148222,106.8462&'
scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(url)
# or just
# query = urlparse(url).query
parsed_query_string = parse_qs(query)
print(parsed_query_string)
lat, long = parsed_query_string['ll'][0].split(',')
print(lat)
print(long)
```

outputs

```
{'ll': ['-6.148222,106.8462'], 'q': ['loc:-6.148222,106.8462']}
-6.148222
106.8462
```

Comment: I'm not using urllib on my code, but I will try it since you are right about the fact that any URL change in the future could potentially break out my code. I've never used urllib, so I need to take a look at how it works. I'm using requests in conjunction with bs4.

Answer (score -1):

use diff regex for latitude and longitude

```
import re
str1="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=6.148222,-106.8462&q=loc:-6.148222,106.8462&"
lat=re.search(r"(-)*\d+(.)\d+",str1).group()

lon=re.search(r",(-)*\d+(.)\d+",str1).group()
print(lat)
print(lon[1:])
```

output

```
6.148222
-106.8462
```

Comment: I've made a litte change to get the "lon" value without the "," at the first. lon=re.search(r",(-)*\d+(.)\d+",str1).group()[1:],  rather than on printing. Thank you!